# Using a wildcard to get all nodes

Tags: r, jsonlite

I'm trying to pull data from a json file using a wildcard.

The data I'm trying to pull are the game stats for every player from this json file.  They are under

http://statsapi-default-elb-prod-876255662.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v1/game/565711/boxscore

I've tested the jsonpath using this website

```
http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/
```

If I enter this json path

teams.*.players.*.person.fullName

I get a list of all the players

```
"Shane Bieber",
"Jon Edwards",
"Max Moroff",
"Jake Bauers",
"Tyler Olson",
"Nick Wittgren",
"Carlos Carrasco",
"Leonys Martin",
"Neil Ramirez",
"Greg Allen",
"Kevin Plawecki",
"Brad Miller",
"Jordan Luplow".
etc...
```

However when I put that code into r I get an error

```
Error: unexpected '*' in "  repos$teams$*"
```

I've tried the following codes

```
repos$teams$*$players$*$person$fullName
repos$teams$[*]$players$[*]$person$fullName
repos$teams$[[*]]$players$[[*]]$person$fullName
```

The end goal is to get all the games stats for each player in to a dataframe

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I'm new to json with R, thought I was doing pretty good, then this hit me between the eyes!  ha!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Neither base R nor the tidy verse support jsonpath. The R language doesn't define `*` to mean wildcard at all. In R, you have to map over collections to extract values. In R, with the `purrr` package I might do something like this

```
# repos <- jsonlite::fromJSON("http://statsapi-default-elb-prod-876255662.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/api/v1/game/565711/boxscore")

library(purrr)
map(repos$teams, pluck, "players") %>% 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% 
  map_chr(pluck, "person", "fullName")
```

First I map over the teams to extract both home and away, then to each of those groups I use the `pluck()` function to get the players. Then I use `unlist()` to combine the lists of players from home/away. Then I map over all the players again using `pluck()` to extract the person$fullName from each one. The `map_chr` will ensure that a character vector is returned. Pluck will name that vector, if you want to drop the names you can can add `%>% unname()` at the end.

Comment: Well, that at least makes me feel a little bit better that R can't do it.  ha!  Your code makes perfect sense, and I see exactly what your saying.  How would I grab the whole stats list?  Would I have to do it one by one and bind the columns or is there a way to grab that section along with the player id or name

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the [rjsonpath](https://github.com/blmoore/rjsonpath) package. It's not on CRAN yet, but is useful here.

Once installed, you could do:

```
json_path(repos,  "$teams..players..person.fullName")
```

or maybe just

```
json_path(repos,  "$..fullName")
```